# How to copy a directory and ignore some directory recursively?

Tags: macos, shell, cp

mac OS. 
I want to copy a directory named "bundleDir" which has some sub directory like ".svn". Also in directory bundleDir there are other directorys which  has ".svn"
 the tree like this

```
bundleDir
    ----.svn
    ----dirM
          ----.svn
          ----a.txt
    ----b.txt
```

I want to copy bundleDir to another directory exclude .svn recursively. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`IFS=$'\n'; for f in $(find bundleDir -depth | grep -v '/\.svn[/$]'); do d=~/target/"${f%/*}"; mkdir -p "$d"; cp -n "$f" "$d"; done`

`cp -R bundleDir ~/target; find ~/target -type d -name .svn -delete`